# How can I reference a C++/CLI project in a silverlight application

Tags: c++, .net, silverlight, command-line-interface

I have a question about C++/CLI and Silverlight. I am currently working on a projet using the MVVM pattern where :

- The business logic is written using C++ DLLs and a C++/CLI wrapper
- I use a Silverlight application for the presentation part.

So I have to use my C++/CLI project in my Silverlight application, however, I can't because my project it's not a Silverlight project.

I've looked on the internet, where I found no suitable solution for my problem yet.

Therefore, I hope that you have a solution for this particular problem.

For the record, I work on Windows Seven using Visual Studio 2010, .NET 4.5 and Silverlight 5.

Thank you.

P.S: Sorry for my English, it's not my mothertongue.

Comment: You can't because your project is a Silverlight project.  Silverlight 5 supports pinvoke but only for trusted apps, the kind that doesn't run in a browser by default.  Silverlight 4 supports COM Automation, same kind of restrictions.

Answer (score 1):

The best solution I found is to create a wcf service which calls the c++ functions.
However, you must use a *HostServiceFactory* in order to make your web services able to find your dlls.

Thanks for your answers